# Loud beep sound from manjaro

Tags: audio, manjaro, bell

I am using Manjaro
When I press backspace in an empty search or when I want to shutdown my PC using the GUI, a loud beep is heard.
Can anyone help me remove this sound?

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux! What version of Manjaro are you using (`cat /etc/*release`)? As you probably guess, it's a notification sound. I _think_ those are handled by either desktop manager or window manager. So what desktop manager do you use? What window manager? Please don't answer in a comment, but edit your question adding new details. Please also don't provide text output as a screenshot, but copy-paste to the question, and enclose it in curly brackets `{ }` to keep the formatting readable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `sudo moprobe pcspkr`. Also, does the beep go away if you run `xset b off` in a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The PC speaker that creates the beep can be blacklisted so it is not loaded when system is booted

This command will create a file to blacklist the speaker

```
echo 'blacklist pcspkr' | sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf
```

[Disable PC Speaker Globally | ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PC_speaker#Globally)

[How to disable thinkpad beeping in manjaro?](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-disable-thinkpad-beeping-in-manjaro/13030)

Answer (score 0):

Run `xset q` in a terminal, and look for “bell percent”. If it isn’t “0” (on Manjaro it seems it is set to “50” by default) then, as @terdon stated, running `xset b off` should fix the issue for you. You can also change the volume (which I believe is represented by the “bell percent” but I am not sure) and pitch as well as duration of the sound if you still want some feedback — this is what I can see by running `man xset`.